# Como obtener el penúltimo elemento de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Hola quisiera obtener el penultimo elemento de un array en javascript.

He utilizado la funcion pop() pero este me devuelve el ultimo, yo quiero ese ultimo -1 pero no he logrado obtenerlo.

```
campos.push(celda);  //Aqui tendo todos los elementos

campos.splice(campos.pop()) // Este me elimina el ultimo
```

alguna sugerencia?  gracias.

Comment: el método `pop()` elimina el elemento del arrayademás de devolverlo. ¿Quieres también sacar el penúltimo elemento del array o sólo acceder a él?

Comment: El objetivo es saber el peultimo y eliminarlo.

Answer (score 6):

En el ejemplo mostrado más abajo:

```
array.length = 5
```

Si intentamos acceder al valor `array[array.length]` nos devolverá el error `index out of bounds` porque estaremos accediendo a una posición del array inexistente, ya que `array[5]` no existe.

Como el primer elemento del array está almacenado en el índice `0` y el último elemento está almacenado en `array.length - 1` (índice `4`), le restamos `2` a la longitud total del array para acceder a la penúltima posición.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array[array.length - 2]);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tu respuesta es muy simple y eso es excelente. Sin embargo, poner sólo código sin dar una breve explicación se considera de baja calidad. Te invito a agregar una breve explicación haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: +1 por mejorar la calidad, es importante para el sitio responder agregando una explicación.

Answer (score 5):

Si queremos un intervalo del array original, podemos usar `slice()`:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

const penultimo = arr.slice(-2,-1);

console.log(penultimo);
```

Explicación: `.slice(inicio, fin)` nos da una rebanada del array, comenzamos en la posición *inicio* = -2 (penúltimo) hasta *fin* = -1 (el último). Para obtener algún elemento del nuevo array, único en este caso: `penultimo[0]`

Comment: Genial Emeeus, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos opciones, usar [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) o usar `pop` dos veces:

```js
let a= [1,2,3,4,5,6];


function penul1(array){
  const ult=array.pop();
  const pen=array.pop();
  array.push(ult); //deshacemos el primer pop
  return pen;
}

function penul2(array) {
  const pen= array.splice(array.length-2,1);
  return pen[0];
}

console.log('Saco el penúltimo:',penul1(a));
console.log('Saco el penúltimo:',penul2(a));
console.log('nos queda', a.toString());
```

Si vas a realizar esta acción varias veces, creo más sensato quitar el último elemento, iterar usando `pop` las veces que necesites y luego volver a meter el último elemento:

```js
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const ult=arr.pop();

while (arr.length>1) {
  console.log('El penúltimo elemento es',arr.pop()); //sacamos todos menos el primero
}

arr.push(ult); //colocamos el último, de nuevo

console.log('El array queda asi:',arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Encuentro dos formas de hacerlo, la primera con *splice* o *slice* (aunque siempre es más recomendable hacer uso de la función *slice*) como indicaba Emeeus en su respuesta o bien puedes hacerlo por [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const arr= [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
   
const {[arr.length - 2] : penultimo} = arr;

console.log(penultimo)
```

Comment: +1 por `destructuring`, pero no veo la necesidad de copiar y pegar lo que ya fue publicado en otra respuesta. Considera eliminarlo de tu respuesta

Comment: Gracias, muy buena respuesta, y la sintaxis esta buena.